# selecting N particular tables from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, bash

I have a mysql db and have 100 tables in it named, table_1, table_2, table_3 etc...
In my bash script I only want to select 10 tables at a time say from table_20 to table_29. I tried the following code:

```
show tables where Tables_in_db REGEXP '^table_[20-29]'
```

but it treats 2,0,9 as separate digits rather than identifying 20 and 29 as numbers.

How should I modify my query?

Comment: `table_NN` is usually a poor way to design a schema.

Comment: well I am just using the db , not designing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex to match the numerical sequence of table names from `table_20` to `table_29` is:

```
^table_2[0-9]
```

So your query should be:

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE Tables_in_db REGEXP '^table_2[0-9]'
```

Comment: It seems I misread the question, this answers the question :) ++

Comment: @sjsam Nothing wrong with your answer, it is certainly related at least.

Comment: I was thinking, why use an external too when `REGEXP` alone would handle it.. Also I read the question like `give me the tables 20 to 29` for which my - now deleted answer - suffices ;)

Comment: @pku : You may accept an answer if it helped. I feel this is the best candidate

Answer (score 0):

If you could use an external tool, then `awk` is your friend, Example :

```
mysql -u root -p -se "show tables from db_name" | awk '/^table_2[0-9]$/'
```

This gives you table_(20-29) as you expect. Note `-s` with mysql to get rid of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'table_%'
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(TABLE_NAME, 'table_', '') AS INT)
LIMIT 20,10;
```

How it works:

1. Get all tables that have specific name convention i.e. starting with `table_`
2. Sort by number suffix
3. Use `LIMIT offset, count`

---

I do not know your specific schema but multiple tables with common prefix could indicate poor design.

Related: [`SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)